# in python merge two dataframes with the merge key of one dataframe contained in key of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes df1 and df2 in order to compare two values info 1 and info 2. The key to merge them is hidden in the name columns. Df1 is 'clean' as it has a first name column and a last name column. Df2, however, is tricky. There is only a name column and the names can be given in different ways. The standard case is first and last name but as shown in the picture below it can contain two names separated by an 'and' or a '&' or it can even be something totally different like a school.

[image]

Here is the dummy data in code:

```
data1 = [['Anna','Tessmann',10], ['Ben','Fachmann',20], ['John','Smith',10]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['FirstName','LastName','Info1'])


data2 = [['Ben Fachmann',30], ['School AAA',40], ['John and Melissa Smith',50], ['Bob & Anna Tessmann',20]]
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name','Info2'])
```

Would anyone know an efficient way to merge these two? Is there the possibility to merge on st like 'df2.Name contains df1.Lastname'? Or I was looking into trying to parse df2.Name, I found nameparser import HumanName but I think it can't deal with 'and' and '&'.

I apologize if something is unclear. Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: I think I understand but you want code that says `if df2.name has 2 names then value / 2 else value then append that to db1`?

Comment: Why `"Anna Tessmann"` has 10 in `Info2` of `df_analysis` ? Also, you have a typo in `data2`, `"Testmann"` instead of `"Tessmann"`. Can you *double-check* ?

Comment: I think it was a typo given the images, I fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a double substring [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import re

pattern1 = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['FirstName']))
pattern2 = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['LastName']))

match1 = df2['Name'].str.extractall(f'(?P<FirstName>{pattern1})').droplevel(1)
match2 = df2['Name'].str.extractall(f'(?P<LastName>{pattern2})').droplevel(1)

out = df1.merge(df2.join(match1).join(match2),
                on=['FirstName', 'LastName'])
```

Output:

```
  FirstName  LastName  Info1                    Name  Info2
0      Anna  Tessmann     10     Bob & Anna Tessmann     20
1       Ben  Fachmann     20            Ben Fachmann     30
2      John     Smith     10  John and Melissa Smith     50
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked wonderfully also with my actual dataset!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make a column that can match names. Then it will work fine.

Here is something that works. It may not always work depending on the uniqueness of the names in the data.

Also, there was a typo in your example data but I fixed it below. (tessmann was testmann)

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['Anna','Tessmann',10], ['Ben','Fachmann',20], ['John','Smith',10]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['FirstName','LastName','Info1'])


data2 = [['Ben Fachmann',30], ['School AAA',40], ['John and Melissa Smith',50], ['Bob & Anna Tessmann',20]]
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name','Info2'])

# make a column to identify which indices in df1 match to df2
df2['merge_index'] = None
for _ind, _row in enumerate(df1.to_dict(orient='records')):
    df2.loc[df2.Name.str.contains(_row['FirstName']) & df2.Name.str.contains(_row['LastName']), 'merge_index'] = _ind

# merge df1 index to df2.merge_index column and select columns to keep
merged = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_on='merge_index')[['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Info1', 'Info2']]
```

Output:
merged

```
      FirstName  LastName  Info1  Info2
3      Anna      Tessmann     10     20
0       Ben      Fachmann     20     30
2      John      Smith        10     50
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution :

```
L1 = df1[["FirstName", "LastName"]].agg(set, axis=1).tolist()
L2 = list(zip([s.split() for s in df2["Name"]], df2["Info2"]))
​
df_analysis = (
  df1.assign(Infos2=[next((v for (lst, v) in L2 if s.issubset(lst)), None) for s in L1])
)
```

Output :

```
print(df_analysis)

  FirstName  LastName  Info1  Infos2
0      Anna  Tessmann     10      20
1       Ben  Fachmann     20      30
2      John     Smith     10      50
```

Answer (score 2):

First, we replace all '&' with 'and' for consistency, then split along 'and' and explode that into multiple rows with the same index.

Then we split and expand into columns. Those with first names only can use backfill from their spouse's last name. We merge this exploded name table back into df2 just on index to match names with info2.

Then it's a straightforward merge with df1.

```
names = df2["Name"].str.replace("&", "and")
names = names.str.split("and").explode()
names = names.str.strip()

names = (
    names.str.split(" ", expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0: "FirstName", 1: "LastName"})
    .fillna(method="bfill")
)

df1.merge(
    names.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True), on=["FirstName", "LastName"]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which is based on the idea of replacing `and` and `&` by the last name in each row of `df2`:

```
(df1.assign(Name = df1['FirstName'] + ' ' + df1['LastName'])
 .merge(df2.assign(Name = df2['Name'].str.replace(
     r'and\s|&\s', lambda x: x.string.split()[-1] + ',', regex=True)
                   .str.split(','))
 .explode('Name'), on='Name', how='left')
 .drop('Name', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  FirstName  LastName  Info1  Info2
0      Anna  Tessmann     10     20
1       Ben  Fachmann     20     30
2      John     Smith     10     50
```